# Why does peeking into std::cin through a boost::iostreams::filtering_istream forever blocks?

Tags: c++, boost

In the below code, I am wrapping `std::cin` into a `boost::iostreams::filtering_istream`. Calling `peek()` on the resulting object seems to block forever since I don't return from `peek()` whatever the number of characters that I type (pressing enter every now and then to flush).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;
  in.push(std::cin); // tried (in.push(boost::ref(std::cin)))

  if ('a' == std::cin.peek()) std::cout << "ok";
  if ('a' == in.peek()) std::cout << "ok"; // blocks whatever the amount of characters typed, I expected it to behave like the std::cin.

  return 0;
}
```

I could not find any indication in the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) that suggests I am not using the library correctly. I tried to wrap `std::cin` with `boost::ref` when pushing it to the filtering stream but it did not change the behavior.

I tested the snippet with Visual Studio 2017 (boost 1.75.0 and 1.70.0) and gcc9.3 (boost 1.72.0) and none worked.

Thank you in advance for your help in figuring out what goes wrong.

Comment: i tried your code in https://wandbox.org/ and it works fine.
try piping your input to your program to see if it fixes your problem.
echo "aaaa" | yourprogram

Comment: You are right. I have just tested it with Visual Studio and it indeed works. My problem holds because I definitely need my program to "interactively read" from std::cin as described in the message. Thank you for this insight though, it sure helps me making progress in understanding what is going wrong.

Comment: I submitted this issue to the boost iostreams github page : https://github.com/boostorg/iostreams/issues/124.